# How to inject a setting from security.yml into a service?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I have a custom service and I want to inject the value of the `check_path` (from `app/config/security.yml`) setting into it. In my service definition I tried using

```
arguments:
  check_path: %security.firewalls.main.form_login.check_path%
```

but that results in this error:

> The service "myService" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter
>   "security.firewalls.main.form_login.check_path".

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

**Edit**
There's a work around where I can first define a variable in `parameters.ini` and then use it in `security.yml` and inject it into my service, but I'd like to avoid that. Needing to 'redeclare' variables in `parameters.ini` seems like it could get messy, especially if I later need to inject even more settings from security.yml. I wouldn't want to have to define something in parameters.ini each time this needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `parameters.yml` (or `parameters.ini` — then use `=` instead of `:`) file:

```
login.check_path: /your/path/here
```

Then go to your `security.yml` and do this:

```
form_login:
    check_path: %login.check_path%
```

Then use this as your argument:

```
arguments: [ %login.check_path% ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, maybe someone else can confirm, but try @security.firewalls.main.form_login.check_path (with the @ instead of quotes to reference config and services)?

Comment: This results in `The service "myService" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.firewalls.main.form_login.check_path".`